# Size of chord in latex pkg. guitar

Tags: fontsize

i use the guitar package. I use the font size of `\large` for my text. But the chord ignors this setting.

```
\begin{large}
\begin{guitar}

[G]This should be[A]a song.

\end{guitar}
\end{large}
```

Does someone can give me a hit, what the problem could be?

Comment: please edit the example so that it is a complete document that people can see the issue and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package uses `\footnotesize` but you can change it when you change the body size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{guitar}

\begin{document}

\begin{guitar}

[G]This should be [A]a song.

\end{guitar}

\begin{large}\renewcommand\guitarPreAccord{\normalsize\strut}
\begin{guitar}

[G]This should be [A]a song.

\end{guitar}
\end{large}
\end{document}
```